# Archived emails vanishing (Outlook 2010)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

I have just archived an Outlook 2003 PST file into what I believe was an Outlook 2003 PST archive.

Archiving was configured to move everything older than 30 days into the archive PST file, however I have checked the archive PST file, and the emails older than 30 days (which were removed from the main PST file during the archiving process) have not appeared there.

File size of Outlook.PST = ~2GB

File size of Archive.PST = ~3GB

There were already some emails in the Archive.PST file before I did this, as it was an archive that was already on the machine (I am fairly certain it is a 2003-format PST file). Unfortunately, as this PST file already had some emails in it, the file size of 3GB doesn't mean much- I can't tell if the file size increased during archiving.

Any idea what might have happened?

What could explain this?

Answer (score 0):

That's a relief. I have just talked to the user, and nothing is missing. It seems she had manually archived the older emails herself. I'll look into what is happening more closely after she's finished work for the day.

I have created a new PST for the archive just so I have peace of mind that it is 2003 format.